# Proving a set of equalities in set theory

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right)
= \kern{-2pt}\sum_{\{j: s_j\in \cup_{i=1}^k A_i\}}\kern{-6pt}p_j
= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{\{j: s_j \in A_i \}} p_j
=\sum_{i=1}^k P(A_i)$$

$$P(A)=\sum_{\{i: s_i \in A \}} p_i$$

Hello,
     I would like to know why this series of equalities holds true. I could not sort out the complex notation after a long time... Could someone please break it down to me in the simplest manner possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true if the sets $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ are pairwise disjoint:

If $s_j \in \cup_{i=1}^k A_i$, by the definition of union, there is $i \in \left\{ 1, \ldots, k \right\}$ such that $s_j \in A_i$. Moreover, since $A_i \cap A_l = \emptyset$ if $l \neq i$, then, there is a UNIQUE $i \in \left\{ 1, \ldots, k \right\}$ such that $s_j = A_i$.

However, if the sets $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ are not pairwise disjoint, it could not hold. Here you have a counterexample:

Suppose you have as possible values of a random variable the set $\Omega = \left\{ 1, 2, 3 \right\}$. Let $A_1 = \left\{ 1\right\}$ and $A_2 = \left\{ 1,2 \right\}$. Let $p_i = P(\text{getting the result }i)$. Since $A_1 \cup A_2 = \left\{ 1,2 \right\}$, in one hand we have
$$P \left( A_1 \cup A_2 \right) = p_1 + p_2$$

But, in the other hand,

$$P \left(A_1\right) + P \left(A_2\right)  = p_1 + (p_1 + p_2)$$.

And, if $p_1 \neq 0$, the equality that that you posted is not true, because you are counting the results in the intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2$ two times.

Now, try to think which changes could you introduce in your initial equality to make it always true. Begin with only two sets ($A_1$ and $A_2$). It will be a nice exercise to understand a bit more of probability and set theory in its basis.

Hope I've been helpfull!